# NextJS production CSS build

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, next.js

I have Custom CSS files for different layouts and there is no problem in dev mode but when I publish my app in production mode Nextjs combine all CSS and makes problem for my layouts.

Comment: did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, after `build` we push all `CSS` and `JS` `chunks` into a `static` folder so that when server ask for the requested page `Next Js` serve it from that `static` folder (depending on the request).

**Server.js** :

```
const staticDir = path.resolve(__dirname, "..", ".next/static");
server.use(compression());
server.use("/_next/static", express.static(staticDir));



    server.get("/_next/*", (req, res) => {
      /* serving _next static content using next.js handler */
      handle(req, res);
    });
    server.get("/static/*", (req, res) => {
      /* serving _next static content using next.js handler */
      handle(req, res);
    });
```

Add below lines in your `_document.js` file and please share the configuration you added in `next.config.js`.

**_document.js**

// Render app and page and get the context of the page with collected side  effects.

```
  const sheets = new ServerStyleSheets();
  const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

  ctx.renderPage = () =>
    originalRenderPage({
      enhanceApp: App => props => sheets.collect(<App {...props} />)
    });

  const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);

  return {
    ...initialProps,
    // Styles fragment is rendered after the app and page rendering finish.
    styles: [
      ...React.Children.toArray(initialProps.styles),
      sheets.getStyleElement()
    ]
  };
};
```